# call to Bitmap.compress does not return - and NO exception

Tags: java, android, bitmap

On Android I sometimes do the following with an image.

It never gets past the bitmapPicture.compress line - it seems to just sit there and hang.

The line above where I get the byte count returns 40000.

I never see compress done, or any other output after 'compress'.

```
try {

    final int COMPRESSION_QUALITY = 100;
    String encodedImage;
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayBitmapStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Log.e("Error","compress" + bitmapPicture.getByteCount());

    bitmapPicture.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,
                    COMPRESSION_QUALITY, byteArrayBitmapStream);
    Log.e("Error","compress done");
    byte[] b = byteArrayBitmapStream.toByteArray();
    Log.e("Error","bytear");
    encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);

    Log.e("Error","JSONDATA encodedImage Returned");
    return encodedImage;

} catch (Exception e) {

    ErrorLogger.AddError(e.getMessage(), 199);
    Log.e("Error","JSONDATA Error"+e.getMessage());
    return null;
}
```

Comment: i'm seeing the same thing. did you ever find a fix?

Comment: Unfortunately I did not, I create a thread and a watch dog class, if it ever took longer then expected I killed the thread and reported the error. Not elegant but couldn't keep dealing with it

Comment: added a bounty - see if we can get it figured out...

Comment: Your ByteArrayOutputStream is empty, how does it return any image?, first assign the image stream to it and than pass it for compression.

Comment: @jitainsharma - `Bitmap.compress` is expected will to fill the ByteArrayOutputStream with bytes on return.

Comment: Does it only happen with a particular bitmap/device/OS setup? I've used this method in a few apps and I don't believe I've encountered this kind of issues

Comment: Have you tried using this without compression? Would you get the same image back? If not, there might be something wrong with the input you're giving the Bitmap. Bitmap -> outputstream -> Bitmap.
 
However if you did get the original image back, please let us know.

Comment: @Ryan Were you able to test this? I am not able to test the proposed solutions on till later in the week
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try calling

```
bitmapPicture.setConfig(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

before the compression. Otherwise, can you provide a little more? Can we see where you declare/load your bitmap?

Comment: Didn't work
 private static Bitmap ARGBBitmap(Bitmap img) {
  return img.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888,true);
 }

 public static String getStringFromBitmaNET(Bitmap bitmapPicture) {
   final int COMPRESSION_QUALITY = 100;
  String encodedImage;
  bitmapPicture = ARGBBitmap(bitmapPicture);
  ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayBitmapStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  bitmapPicture.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, COMPRESSION_QUALITY,
    byteArrayBitmapStream);
  byte[] b = byteArrayBitmapStream.toByteArray();
  encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
  return encodedImage;
}

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code:

```
Bitmap decoded = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(b.toByteArray()));
Log.e("Compressed dimensions", decoded.getWidth()+" "+decoded.getHeight());
```